# Simulating Winkey behaviour in C#

Tags: c#, taskbar

I want to simulate pressing WinKey + digit to switch between to application in taskbar.

Is there a way to do this with managed code or I have to use win32 API?
I tried to use [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).SendWait with something like "^{TAB}2" but this writes 1 in the 
field of Start Menu. Nor does "(^{TAB})1" works.

How can I pass WinKey to SendKeys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research showed that without the use of third party tools like AutoHotKey you can't really simulate the windows key combination shortcuts without the use of the win32 API.

This post showed a very easy implementation of the win32 API though. Just create a class and call on it when you need to. Best part is that it works using any key you want by passing in a Keys enum value

- [SendKeys.Send and Windows Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407584/sendkeys-send-and-windows-key)