# Programmatically open charm bar, power bar and start menu with C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-8, charms-bar

How to programatically open:

- Charm Bar
- Power Options
- Start Menu

in windows 8?

I want to be able to open them from within my c# application

Cannot find the documentation I need

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet sending the Windows key (and the other key, as needed), would be sufficient.

Here is another post on how to do so with an API call.

[SendKeys.Send and Windows Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407584/sendkeys-send-and-windows-key)

To open...

- ... the Start Screen - just send the Windows key.
- ... the Charms - send the Windows key + C.
- ... the settings Charms bar (closet to the power options) - send the Windows key + I.

Comment: Going to Start Screen won't work if you're already in start screen... You need to minimize everything and then send LWin.
To Minimize all see here: https://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/c-show-desktop/