# invoking Windows 8 charmbar from wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

How can one invoke Windows 8 charmbar from a wpf application.

I know this can be done by simulating the key stroke such as win + c from application but the problem is the the same combination is used to hide the charmbar.

I have a wpf application that has a button named show charmbar but the problem is if the same button is clicked when already the charmbar is open it acts as a guide charmbar .

Or else could some body guide me on how tho get the visibility of charmbar. Such as at a given moment is the charmbar visible or not.

Comment: someone asked this before and never got a real answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149603/programmatically-open-charm-bar-power-bar-and-start-menu-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

The truth is a charmbar cannot be opened programatically in metro app development 
for metro you can access various charms menu like settings share.

Here's a full sample for that 
[metro charms](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Invoke-All-Charms-fa8399ed)

But for c# wpf app

Heres a SO answer and I guess it works :)

[open charms c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470664/closing-the-windows-8-charm-bar)

take a look. :)