# How to open 2nd Window Selection menu(Start+P) with C#?

Tags: c#, forms, windows

As title says everything clear. I want to open this menu via my Windows Application. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6407690/440030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KeyDown(ConsoleKey.LeftWindows);
        KeyDown(ConsoleKey.P);
        KeyUp(ConsoleKey.LeftWindows);
        KeyUp(ConsoleKey.P);
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
    private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
    private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
    public static void KeyDown(ConsoleKey vKey)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    }
    public static void KeyUp(ConsoleKey vKey)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code like in this post:

[SendKeys.Send and Windows Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407584/sendkeys-send-and-windows-key)

to send your Windows+P keystrokes.