# Sending global keys to another app

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send the F7 keys to a 3rd party app, Macro Creator.

I tried finding its main window handle then forwarding the key through SendKeys. This did work when the app has not started execting the macro.

When the macro is running, I cant send keys anymore from my C# app. However, the app does get the key from other apps, wherever I am, when pressing F7, Macro Creator does what it is programmed to do.

I even used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407584/sendkeys-send-and-windows-key) to check if I'm doing a mistake, I tried with LWin and it works but still MC does not catch it.

Is there any other method to use?

Comment: Windows applications are sometimes particular about focus. Also, are you sure you don't need to send it to a different handle when the macro is running?

Comment: @BurnsBA When started, the app has two handles. I iterated through all processes whose title is the title of this software and sent the keys to both handles. No luck.