# grow current window using keyboard shortcut

Tags: powershell

I am trying to grow the current window using keyboard shortcut (windows + Up arrow button)

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("+(^{ESC}{UP})");
```

the combinaison does not work correctly

Comment: take a look at the comment(s): [Here.](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2234139-script-who-interacts-with-a-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, **[`[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys) does *not* directly support sending sending keystrokes based on the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key**.

To do so, **a P/Invoke solution is required**, which requires on-demand compilation of C# code via the [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) cmdlet, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6407690/45375):

```cs
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms -UsingNamespace System.Windows.Forms -Namespace demo -Name SendKeyExt  -MemberDefinition  @'
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

  private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
  private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;

  public static void SendKeysWithWinKey(string keys = null) {
    keybd_event((byte) Keys.LWin, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keys)) { SendKeys.SendWait(keys.ToLowerInvariant()); }
    keybd_event((byte) Keys.LWin, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  }
'@
```

The above defines type `[demo.SendKeyExt]`, whose static `::SendKeysWithWinKey()` method:

- accepts a string describing a key combination as supported by [`[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Send/SendWait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send), e.g, `"{up}"`
- and sends that key combination - using `.SendWait()`, for technical reasons - *while programmatically holding down the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key* (note that the key combination is converted to lowercase for technical reasons; it ensures that letters such as `X` are correctly recognized as to be *combined* with the Windows key).

Note that you pay a performance penalty for the ad-hoc compilation performed by `Add-Member`, but only *once per session*.

Once the type is defined, you can use it as follows:

```sh
# Maximize the current window.
# Same as pressing WinKey+Up-Arrow
[demo.SendKeyExt]::SendKeysWithWinKey('{up}')

# Maximize the current window only *vertically* (+ == Shift)
# Same as pressing WinKey+Shift+Up-Arrow
[demo.SendKeyExt]::SendKeysWithWinKey('+{up}')
```