# Send a "tab" keystroke in powershell

Tags: powershell, sendkeys, keystroke

I am trying to send a "TAB" key press, wait 2 secs, then send an "ENTER" key press, but it is not working.

Here is what I tried.

```
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms -UsingNamespace System.Windows.Forms -Namespace demo -Name SendKeyExt  -MemberDefinition  @'
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

  private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
  private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;

  public static void SendKeysWithWinKey(string keys = null) {
    keybd_event((byte) Keys.LWin, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keys)) { SendKeys.SendWait(keys.ToLowerInvariant()); }
    keybd_event((byte) Keys.LWin, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  }
'@

[demo.SendKeyExt]::SendKeysWithWinKey('{TAB}')

sleep -Seconds 2

[demo.SendKeyExt]::SendKeysWithWinKey('ENTER')
```

Comment: It looks like you took the bulk of your code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69520525/45375), in which case you should provide attribution. However, note that that code is about sending keystrokes _with the Windows key held down_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
$vb = New-Object -ComObject wscript.Shell

$vb.SendKeys('{TAB}')
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
$vb.SendKeys('~')
```