# what is the SendKey for Windows Key

Tags: c#, windows, key, sendkeys

I want to know the sendkey for windows key (that key in keyboard with windows Flag on it)

[image]

Comment: use the mentioned link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546069/simulate-windows-key-and-key-to-zoom-in

Comment: top question in the Related column.. - [How to press the windows button programmatically using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437405/how-to-press-the-windows-button-programmatically-using-c-sharp-sendkeys?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can easely call the windows flag key. You will need to p/invoke an API function instead, I think it was keybd_event to send the Windows key.

check [Click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31261/Full-Screen-WPF-Application-with-a-Low-Level-Keybo) Or [Click Here](http://babysmash.codeplex.com/)